# Inserting JSON data to sqlite - OperationalError: unrecognized token "{"

Tags: python, json, sqlite, pysqlite

I'm doing something like this in my code:

```
import sqlite3
...
sqlString=company['name']+","+simplejson.dumps(info)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO companyInfo VALUES("+sqlString+")")
```

but I'm getting the following error:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO companyBlobs VALUES("+valueString+")")
    sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "{"

I guess this is a problem with the escaping of the JSON data, but not sure how to fix it.
Ideas?

Comment: I know what you're saying, but I'm doing a very large number of queries to an API and I need to have everything as JSON before processing the data, so I'm just temporarily storing the JSON in sqlite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use parametrized query:

```
sqlString=company['name']+","+simplejson.dumps(info)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO companyInfo VALUES (?)", (sqlString, ))
```

this will automatically escape your inputs.